# Zip/tar the generated jar file along with other file

Tags: java, maven, zip, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I need to zip the generated jar file after running the `mvn clean deploy`.
But i am facing problem with it.
I am using assembly plugin and my `assembly.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
   <id>bin</id>
   <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
   <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
   </formats>
   <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
         <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/process.sh</directory>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      </fileSet>
      <fileSet>
         <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
         <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
         </includes>
      </fileSet>
   </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

and `pom.xml` looks like below.

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
           <descriptors>
              <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
           </descriptors>
           <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase>
              <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
              <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

In above case i tried to tar the entire `target` folder. It got compressed but there was no files.
What am doing is first executing `mvn clean` then executing `mvn clean deploy`.

I just want the generated jar/war file to be compressed after execution of `mvn clean deploy`.

after running `mvn clean deploy` its zipping the `.jar` file, its zipping the `.jar.original`. which is of 8kb file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A JAR file is essentially a ZIP file with another extension. It doesn't make sense to zip a JAR file.

Comment: It doesn't make sense okay. But in my scenario i needed it. Its zipping the `jar` but not the proper `jar` which i wanted. When i do `mvn clean deploy` it generates files `app-0.0.1.jar`, `app-0.0.1.jar.original` and `app-0.0.1.zip`. The zip file has  `app-0.0.1.jar.original` instead of  `app-0.0.1.jar`

Comment: any updates on this??

Comment: When i used `mvn clean install assembly:single` command its zipping the proper `35mb` jar with `.sh` script. But when i tried `mvn clean deploy assembly:single` its picking `.jar.original` jar with `.sh` script and its of `80kb` fzip file.

Comment: attaching the `.xml`files https://gist.github.com/tejas1493/5a1a5f7d6696f7fcabe51448e5914597